# Como selecionar os registros que não possuam relacionamento entre 3 tabelas

Tags: sql

Supondo que eu tenha 3 tabelas: Empresa, Usuarios e UsuariosEmpresa (que relaciona as outras duas tabelas)

### Empresa

```
+----+----------+--+
| ID |   NOME   |  |
+----+----------+--+
|  1 | Empresa1 |  |
|  2 | Empresa2 |  |
|  3 | Empresa3 |  |
|  4 | Empresa4 |  |
+----+----------+--+
```

### Usuários

```
+----+--------+--+
| ID |  NOME  |  |
+----+--------+--+
|  1 | Joao   |  |
|  2 | Pedro  |  |
|  3 | Maria  |  |
|  4 | Fátima |  |
+----+--------+--+
```

`

### UsuariosEmpresa

```
+----+------------+------------+--+
| ID | usuario_id | empresa_id |  |
+----+------------+------------+--+
|  1 |          1 |          1 |  |
|  2 |          1 |          2 |  |
|  3 |          2 |          1 |  |
|  4 |          2 |          3 |  |
|  5 |          3 |          1 |  |
|  6 |          3 |          2 |  |
|  7 |          3 |          3 |  |
+----+------------+------------+--+
```

Eu gostaria de selecionar todos registros da tabela UsuariosEmpresa aonde não exista uma relacionamento entre Usuário e Empresa. Neste exemplo seria algo assim:

### Resultado

```
+------+------------+------------+
|  ID  | usuario_id | empresa_id |
+------+------------+------------+
| 1    |          1 |          1 |
| 2    |          1 |          2 |
| null |          1 |          3 |
| null |          1 |          4 |
| 3    |          2 |          1 |
| null |          2 |          2 |
| 4    |          2 |          3 |
| null |          2 |          4 |
| 5    |          3 |          1 |
| 6    |          3 |          2 |
| 7    |          3 |          3 |
| null |          3 |          4 |
| null |          4 |          1 |
| null |          4 |          2 |
| null |          4 |          3 |
| null |          4 |          4 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

Coloquei todos os registros para ilustrar, mas eu gostaria de selecionar somente os registros que NÃO tenham relacionamento ( do exemplo os que estão null )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucas, segue uma sugestão utilizando um *Cross Join* entre as tabelas de empresas e usuários para gerar todas as combinações possíveis entre essas tabelas, e um filtro com o operador *Exists* para obter no resultado somente as combinações que não existem na tabela UsuariosEmpresa:

```
select
  u.id as usuario_id,
  e.id as empresa_id
from Empresa as e
cross join Usuarios as u
where
  not exists
    (select 1 from UsuariosEmpresa as ue
     where ue.usuario_id = u.id and ue.empresa_id = e.id)
```

Espero que ajude